# Confused about the measure of the Cantor Set, and how to reconcile this with there being points not at the endpoints

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, cantor-set

I know that there are points not at the endpoints of the intervals we have removed in the cantor set, such as $1\over 4$, because we can represent the numbers remaining by all ternary strings using only $0$'s or $2$'s. However, this seems to contradict the fact that we keep on removing $1\over 3$ of what we have at each stage of removing the middle third interval, so eventually we will get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\frac 2 3)^n = 0$ left, such that nothing remains except the endpoints. How can I reconcile these 2 things, finding the correct way to think about them?

Comment: The problem is precisely that the fact that you are removing a total length of 1 does *not* mean you are left only with endpoints. You agree you are left with the numbers that have a ternary expansion that contains no 1s. But there are uncountably many such points left; yet there are only countably many endpoints. You are left with more than just endpoints.

Comment: By the way, you *remove* one third of what you had; you *retain* two thirds.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin why does  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\frac 2 3)^n = 0$ specifically not mean that we are left with empty spaces after we remove everything except the endpoints?

Comment: Why do you expect that measure zero implies that a subset is countable?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am seeing that the limit I mentioned represents the space which is left save for the endpoints when we remove everything, simply because the space is $2 \over 3$ of what we had in the last iteration of removing the middle third. So after we have finished removing everything, it seems that there is nothing left save for the endpoints, due to this limit. Why is this view wrong?

Comment: Because what's correct is that the limit you mention represents the space which is left save for everything in the Cantor set. After we have finished removing everything, there is not left save for the Cantor set.

Comment: That is exactly what the set theory tells us.

Comment: You have two statements contradicting each other: for the first one, you have a solid mathematical proof. For the second statement, you do not have any proof, it just "seems" to be true. Which of the two statements should you accept as a true one? A mathematician will always take the first statement.

Comment: Your conceptual error is thinking that the limit being zero *requires* you to be left with only endpoints. *That's just not true*, and as long as you hold on to that incorrect "conclusion", you cannot reconcile it. You **never** remove "everything but the endpoints". At each step you have lots of stuff other than endpoints. Why does *that* not tell you that you can have more than "just endpoints"?

Comment: @arturoMagidin I certainly see how there is much more than endpoints due to the argument you have mentioned. I am merely trying to correct my view of how  the limit contradicts this. Is it incorrect to say that at each step, the Cantor set's cardinality is $2 \over 3$ of what it was at the previous step?

Comment: @LeeMosher is the space left over not $1 \over 3$ of the previous step, not $2 \over 3$? Could you please explain why $2 \over 3$ is not what is left over of the Cantor set at each step?

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect to say the *cardinality* is two thirds what it was. The *total length* is two thirds what it was. So what? Length zero does not mean "just the endpoints", it means "length zero".

Comment: @AlexanderD. cardinality does not allow fractions.  All the sets involved in these example have the same (Uncountable) cardinality.

Answer (score 2):

> so eventually we will get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\frac 2 3)^n = 0$ left, such that nothing remains except the endpoints.

This sentence is where your intuition has led you astray, and led you to leap to an unjustified conclusion.  You are making a completely spurious connection between the total length of the set of remaining points (which can be defined rigorously as the infimal sum of lengths of intervals needed to cover the set), and the quality of being an endpoint.

At the risk of playing psychologist, this may be because subconsciously, you have reversed the implication $$S \text{ is the set of endpoints of disjoint intervals} \implies S \text{ has length }0\text{,}$$
which is true, to
$$S \text{ has length }0 \implies S \text{ is the set of the endpoints of disjoint intervals,}$$
which is false.

The first example to correct your intuition, even though it won't directly clarify the Cantor set issue for you, should be that any countable set, even a dense one such as $\mathbb Q$, must have length $0$.  To see this, simply cover the points with a sequence of intervals of length $\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$.

But certainly $\mathbb Q$ is not the set of endpoints for a union of disjoint intervals.

Now that you realize that length zero doesn't have anything to do with endpoints, it should be easier to accept this Cantor example, which you can use to further kill off any intuition you might be tempted to have that $0$ length even implies countable.